# How to structure the network requests on an iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, networking, request

So, I'm still an unexperienced developer and I need some help with an app I'm currently developing.

The app consists of different tab-views. The first two of them rely on data that is stored on a database. The first database I created myself with Firebase, because it is a news-section, which I need to update regularly myself. The second tab-view needs to request simple data from two different databases, which both return data in the JSON format. The App then should save the data of both databases  as custom objects in two different arrays, which both will be used to compare the data sets and display some of the data in a table view.

The thing I'm struggeling with is where to trigger those network requests without compromising the user's experience. What is the best practice to do so? At the moment, the first network request is in the viewWillLoad() method of the associated viewcontroller. But I'm not quite happy with that because there is a small delay between opening the app and displaying those news. Additionally is it better to download the data and then save it locally on the device and compare it to the data online or to download it everytime? It's not a lot of data and just text - no pictures, videos whatsoever - and little pieces of the data change regularly and most of the data changes only twice a year)

Thanks for helping me out here, because I somehow did not find a lot of information on how to structure those requests and I hope that some more experienced programmers might be able to help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kick off network tasks in your `AppDelegate` in:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

Just make sure you throttle it so you don't do it too often.

Generally, you want to cache/store your network results and display the cached values.  This is especially important if the user is in an area with limited or no network availability when they launch your app.

If you're using CoreData then updating the data will update your table view automatically.  If not, then you can call reload() on your table view in the completion block of your network update, or post a notification that your view controller is listening for, and update then.

Either way be sure to update using a URLSession data task on a background queue.